# Add & remove multiple classes with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, html-lists

```
 <div id="siteFeelingBannar" class="shadowVeryMild">
     <ul>
       <li><div class="autologinImage"></div><span class="statusHover">Affectionate</span></li>
       <li><div class="autologinImage hidden"><span class="statusHover autologinMargin">Annoyed</span></li>
       <li><div class="autologinImage hidden"><span class="statusHover autologinMargin">Anxious</span></li>
       <li><div class="autologinImage hidden"><span class="statusHover autologinMargin">Chatty</span></li>
       <li><div class="autologinImage hidden"><span class="statusHover autologinMargin">Content</span></li>
       <li><div class="autologinImage hidden"><span class="statusHover autologinMargin">Curious</span></li>
       <li><div class="autologinImage hidden"><span class="statusHover autologinMargin">Ecstatic</span></li>
       <li><div class="autologinImage hidden"><span class="statusHover autologinMargin">Excited</span></li>
       <li><div class="autologinImage hidden"><span class="statusHover autologinMargin">Free</span></li>
     </ul>
 </div>
```

I have the above piece of code that gives a drop down list so people can choose their current feeling.

You will notice the first `li` is slightly different to the rest:

```
  <li><div class="autologinImage"></div><span class="statusHover">Affectionate</span></li>
```

This is the currently selected `li` as it doesn't have the `div.hidden` class (adds a img - tick to show selected) and it doesn't have the `span.autologinMargin` class (gives the other `li` items some required spacing so they all lineup) set.

I've been trying to write the jQuery to allow this to switch.
eg: if someone clicks on a different `li` then this one has the `div.hidden` removed and `span.autologinMargin` removed and the previously selected one has these 2 classes added.

Can someone help give me a push in the right direction with this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

```
$('#siteFeelingBannar li').click(function(){
    // Add the class to div and spans
    $(this).siblings().find('div').addClass('hidden');
    $(this).siblings().find('span').addClass('autologinMargin');

    // Remove the classes from div and span.
    $(this).find('div').removeClass('hidden');
    $(this).find('span').removeClass('autologinMargin');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Simplify it by adding the class to the `li`, and then style using child selectors.

That way all you need to do is add/remove the class from the `li` and not the descendant elements.

```
var lis = $('#siteFeelingBannar li').click(function() {
    lis.not('.hidden').addClass('hidden');
    $(this).removeClass('hidden')
});
```

---

```
<div id="siteFeelingBannar" class="shadowVeryMild">
 <ul>
   <li><div class="autologinImage"></div><span class="statusHover">Affectionate</span></li>
   <li class="hidden"><div class="autologinImage"><span class="statusHover">Annoyed</span></li>
   <li class="hidden"><div class="autologinImage"><span class="statusHover">Anxious</span></li>
   <li class="hidden"><div class="autologinImage"><span class="statusHover">Chatty</span></li>
   <li class="hidden"><div class="autologinImage"><span class="statusHover">Content</span></li>
   <li class="hidden"><div class="autologinImage"><span class="statusHover">Curious</span></li>
   <li class="hidden"><div class="autologinImage"><span class="statusHover">Ecstatic</span></li>
   <li class="hidden"><div class="autologinImage"><span class="statusHover">Excited</span></li>
   <li class="hidden"><div class="autologinImage"><span class="statusHover">Free</span></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

---

```css
#siteFeelingBannar > ul > li { ... }
#siteFeelingBannar > ul > li > div.autologinImage { ... }
#siteFeelingBannar > ul > li > div.autologinImage > span.statusHover { ... }

#siteFeelingBannar > ul > li.hidden { ... }
#siteFeelingBannar > ul > li.hidden > div.autologinImage { ... }
#siteFeelingBannar > ul > li.hidden > div.autologinImage > span.statusHover { ... }
```

Comment: Classes are not getting added or removed to/from span.

Comment: @Virendra: Read the whole answer.

Comment: Hi @AdamRackis. Back for a little while anyway. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use code like this that adds the class to all .autologinImage elements and then removes it from the click on element:

```
$("#siteFeelingBannar .autologinImage").click(function() {
    $(this).closest("ul").find(".autologinImage").addClass("hidden");
    $(this).removeClass("hidden");
});
```

You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/ECrHP/

You will also have to fix a `<div>` nesting inconsistency on your first `<li>` in your HTML.  The `<span>` should be inside the `<div>` rather than after it like all the other ones.

There's no need to dynamically add/remove the autologinMargin class as you can control that with only CSS based on whether the parent is hidden or not.  In fact, you probably don't even need that class.  Just set a default rule and override that if .hidden is above it.

If you're willing to move the classes that are now on the div up to the li and adjust the CSS appropriately, then the code can be even simpler:

```
$("#siteFeelingBannar li").click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("hidden").siblings().addClass("hidden");
});
```

Comment: This would not add and remove classes to/from span.

Comment: @Virendra - It adds and removes from the div which is where the existing "hidden" class is.  We assume that's what the OP wants to add/remove.  The autologinMargin class can be removed entirely and the that issue handled entirely with CSS.

Answer (score 1):

The earlier answers aren't noticing that the classes are on a nested `<div>`, not the `<li>`.

```
$("#siteFeelingBannar li").click(function() {
    $(this).find("div").removeClass("hidden").end().find("span").removeClass("autologinMargin");
    $(this).siblings().find("div")addClass("hidden").end().find("span").addClass("autologinMargin");
});
```

Comment: This would not add and remove classes to/from span.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try the switch class property built into jquery.

```
$('.classname').hover( function(){
    $(this).stop(false, true).switchClass("classname");
}, function(){
    $(this).stop(false, true).switchClass("2ndclassname);
});
```

Is an example.

Comment: `switchClass` is part of jQueryUI, not jQuery core.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a class to the selected `li`, lets say `selected`.  Then you can use that to find the selected `li` and add the appropriate classes to its children.

Something like this:

```
$(".selected").find("autologinImage").addClass("hidden").end()
              .find("statusHover").addClass("autologinMargin").end()
              .removeClass("selected");
```

I would consider instead defining your css so that you don't have to remove and add these classes.  Something like this:

```
.autologinMargin{
    visibility: hidden;
}

.selected .autologinMargin{
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Also, using `visibility` will allow you to keep the margin steady since the image will still take up space.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/joshsmith/p6rW2/).

```
$('#siteFeelingBannar li').on('click', function() {
    if (!$(this).children('.autologinImage').hasClass('hidden')) {
        // Do nothing
    } else {
        $('.autologinImage').not('hidden').addClass('hidden');
        $(this).find('div.autologinImage').removeClass('hidden');
    }
});
```